# Pointing cPanel root domain to Netlify

Tags: heroku, dns, cpanel, netlify

I've a domain let's call it example.com that is hosted in a shared server with cPanel (the DNS of the domain are pointing to the shared server). In this server I've some subdomains and my email accounts. 
I want to point only my root domain to a Netlify using their custom domain. Like if a person access example.com it redirects to Netlify but if a person sends an email it redirects to the shared server or if access the subdomains also go to the shared server.

Is that possible to configure via DNS Zone Editor in cPanel?

Big thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### Short Answer: YES

### Longer answer:

Netlify has [documented custom domain setup](https://www.netlify.com/docs/custom-domains) rather well, since it is probably the most asked about feature.

As of this writing you can setup an apex (bare, naked) domain (example.com) to their load balancer IP (104.198.14.52) using an `A` record. If possible you could setup an ANAME or ALIAS record if your DNS provider has the option (most don't). When setting up a sub-domain (example: www), use a CNAME record and point it to the `your-site-name-here.netlify.com` value.

[image]

You can read about the advantages of setting up a sub-domain rather than using the bare domain. There are speed advantages on the CDN.

Comment: FWIW: In [this Netlify blog post](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/03/26/how-to-set-up-netlify-dns-custom-domains-cname-and-a-records/) there are further details why Netlify strongly recommends using the **www** subdomain approach as the primary domain rather than a **non-www** apex domain.